# MongoDB - Way of update a specific element in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-update

To update a specific element in the array on MongoDB collection.

MongoDB data -

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63608e3c3b74ed27b5bdf703"),
  placename: "khulna",
  frnds: [
    { name: "osama", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "lotid", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "haris", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "atiq", cost: "2121" } ],
},
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63608e3c3b74ed27b5bdf703"),
  plmarshal: "narishal",
  frnds: [
    { name: "ojda", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "majid", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "nafis", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "rofiq", cost: "2121" } ],
},
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63608e3c3b74ed27b5bdf703"),
  placename: "latin america",
  frnds: [
    { name: "mamun", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "lotifa", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "sajid", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "natiq", cost: "2121" } ],
}
```

I want to update `frnds` arrays with the specific element that matches by name. I try this way but it's not working.

```js
const query = { name: "khulna", "frnds.name": "osama"};
const updateDocument = { $set: {frnds: { name: "rasana", cost: "212871" } } };
const result = await db.collection(<collection_name>).updateOne(query, updateDocument);
```

After the update, the document like -

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63608e3c3b74ed27b5bdf703"),
  placename: "khulna",
  frnds: [
    { name: "rasana", cost: "212871" }, ////  previus { name: "osama", cost: "2121" }
    { name: "lotid", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "haris", cost: "2121" },
    { name: "atiq", cost: "2121" } ],
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your query ?
"name": "khulna" shouldn't be "placename": "khulna" ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Should be `placename` but not `name`. Otherwise it will not filter any document to be update.
2. The current `$set` will override the `frnds` array to object. You need to use `$[<identifier>]` positional filtered operator with `arrayFilters`.

```
db.collection.update({
  "placename": "khulna",
  "frnds.name": "osama"
},
{
  $set: {
    "frnds.$[f]": {
      name: "rasana",
      cost: "212871"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "f.name": "osama"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kb4Ifek6vhW)

```js
const query = {
  "placename": "khulna",
  "frnds.name": "osama"
};
const updateDocument = {
  $set: {
    "frnds.$[f]": {
      name: "rasana",
      cost: "212871"
    }
  }
};
const result = await db.collection(<collection_name>).updateOne(query, updateDocument, {
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "f.name": "osama"
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: ``$set: {
    "frnds.$[f]": {
    `` what is 'f' ?

Comment: `f` is an identifier as a reference to the document which is matched based on stated matching condition in `arrayFilters`. You may check [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) for more info.

Comment: If ```frnds: [ { name: "ojda", cost: "2121", role: "developer", image: "httpss....." } ]``` like that. The method re write all properties. but it unwanted. how to replace just ```name: "ojda", cost: "2121"``` not all properties.

Comment: For such scenario, you need to specify each properties in the array as this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0in-EE1cKkH).